# Read line into variables

Tags: freepascal

I want to read a file row into variables.

Structure of the file is just:

```
CityNameWithoutSpace ProductName ProductCount
```

Here is my code:

```
procedure TmainForm.readProcutsBtnClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  i: Integer;
  productCity: string;
  productName: string;
  productCount: Integer;
  productFileIn: TextFile;

begin

  assignFile(productFileIn, 'termek.txt');
  reset(productFileIn);
  i := 0;
  while not EOF(productFileIn) do
      begin
         i := i + 1;
        readLn(productFileIn, productCity, productName, productCount);
  end;
  closefile(productFileIn);

end;
```

The problem is that it throws an exception.

If I am just using `readLn(productFileIn, productCity);` that works. `productCity` will be the whole row.

But how can I split the row by spaces into these variables?

EDIT:

Doc is so poor and totally confusing: [readLn](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/readln.html) referenc to [read](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/read.html), read use some "magic" I really do not understand char `C`.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/read.html) show `Args: Arguments' but like you mentioned, do a poor job of correlating `Arguments` to `V1`, `V2`, etc. If you put your product variables in an array, does it work?

Comment: I'll check it now, thx

Comment: @eclecticist I've tired this, but gives me runtime error: https://pastebin.com/baKnf7qU

Comment: Read the whole line into one string, then split the string into your variables.

Comment: Whatever you do, it will always read the entire line into the first string, simply because, unlike a number, a string is not delimited by anything, except perhaps a newline. So do what @LURD says.

Comment: what about the doc? V1, V2, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to read the entire line into one string and then split it into the variables. As @Rudy says, the `ReadLn()` operation for strings cannot know how to delimit a string.

See my example below, where the entire file is loaded into a string list. After that all list items are splitted into an array of product records.

```
type
  TProductRec = record
    productCity: string;
    productName: string;
    productCount: Integer;
  end;

var
  productArray : array of TProductRec;
  aList : TStringList;
  i : Integer;
  sArray : TStringArray;
begin
  aList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    aList.LoadFromFile('termek.txt');
    SetLength(productArray,aList.Count);
    for i := 0 to aList.count-1 do begin
      sArray := aList[i].Split([' ']);
      if Length(sArray) = 3 then begin
        productArray[i].productCity := sArray[0];
        productArray[i].productName := sArray[1];
        productArray[i].productCount := StrToInt(sArray[2]);
      end;
    end;
    // Do something with the product record array
  finally
    aList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

*// Disclaimer: untested, but you get the picture*

Comment: need some time to check it, thank you. 2 days, I will response.

Comment: There is no `SplitString()` function in FPC (nothing found in sources at least). But [`TStringHelper.Split`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/tstringhelper.split.html) in the `SysUtils` unit (not sure about version where it was introduced BTW)